# Syntax error (missing operator), query has nested JOINs and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to build a query that uses a JOIN and GROUP BY, as follows:

```
select r.id,r.[full name],r.[start date],min(work_date) 
from 
(resource r
left join
resourceVendorHistory rvh
on
r.id=rvh.resourceid)
left join
resource_activities ra
on
r.id=ra.resourceid
group by r.id,r.[full name],r.[start date]
where
rvh.resourceid is null
and
ra.id is not null
order by
ra.work_date asc
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'r.[start date] where rvh.resourceid is null and ra.id is not null'.
```

Is there something special that I have to do to separate the second JOIN from the GROUP BY?

Comment: should `group by r.id,r.[full name],r.[start date]` not be at the end, ??

Comment: I believe `WHERE` clause should precede `GROUP BY`

Comment: @PM77-1, yes, that fixes it.  I also needed to add `work_date` to my GROUP BY clause.  i'll accept that if you post as answer.